# Why do some systems sort longer strings before their substrings

Tags: string, sorting

In some systems, I find that when sorting is alphabetic ascending, `mystring` sorts after `mystringbutlonger`.  Why would this be?  It seems to me that the shorter string should be first.

I've seen this in multiple places including file systems and various applications.

Comment: Why do you think the shorter string should be first?

Comment: What systems, and what programming languages? Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: The shorter string could be first if it's null-terminated (0 would sort numerically first), but also just because it contains less data.  That just makes sense to me.  Hence the question:  Why would it be sorted otherwise?

Comment: I don't have concrete examples at the moment.  I'll have to compile them, and maybe reask the question later.

Comment: There could be invisible characters in the strings that are affecting the sorting. Or the sort is following some linguistic rules that are not obvious to native English-speakers. For example, in Dutch, "m" comes between "i" and "ij". In Thai, the second letter of the word is the primary sort key, not the first letter.